# How can I use a cake element in to jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp-3.x

I'm using CakePHP 3, let me tell you what I'm trying to do, is to display the cake element in a div using a screen width condition, it throws the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. From already I tell you that nothing happens with the syntax, no comma, period, etc. I'm missing.

What I need to know is the correct way to put the element helper inside jquery This one: `<?= $ this->element('Search/Legislacion/form-search-legis') ?>`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var width = $(document).width(),
            search_form_legis = "<?= $this->element('Search/Legislacion/form-search-legis') ?>"; 

        // console.log(width);

        if(width >= 576){
            $('#searchDesktop').html(search_form_legis);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your syntax looks correct, so if you aren't getting the desired output then there might be an issue with your PHP function `$this->element()`

Comment: Exactly and that's why I ask if anyone knows the correct way to put the equivalent of the function in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just dump HTML into a JavaScript string, as soon as the first single/double quote occurs, it will break things as that will close the string, just look at the source of the page that is being delivered, there will be something like this:

```js
search_form_legis = "<form method="POST" action="/url">...";
```

Obviously that's broken syntax.

If you want to place data from PHP in JavaScript, then it is advised to use `json_encode()`, it will transform the data into the correct format.

```js
var search_form_legis = <?= json_encode(
    $this->element('Search/Legislacion/form-search-legis')
) ?>;
```

A string, as in your case, will automatically be quoted and escaped, ie you don't even need to put quotes around it, it will looks something like this:

```js
var search_form_legis = "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"/url\">...";
```

That being said, if there isn't an overly good reason to not output the content at all, then you might want to consider using CSS rules to hide/show it instead, something along the lines of:

```css
#searchDesktop {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    #searchDesktop {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right to use the json_encode () method, thank you very much, this method solves the problem as you say. CSS is not an option in my case since I have to display this form at two different screen sizes with different styles and I have problem with duplicate id!
And so I chose to use jQuery, thanks again